# Not able to replace String while reading the file

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, sed

The final.txt looks like:

```
build/create_changes.sh
build/create_changes.sh-meta.xml
src/aura/camping/camping.design
src/aura/camping/camping.design-meta.xml
```

And the code looks like this:

```
if [ -e final.txt ]
then
    ARRAY=()
    while read CFILE
    do
        echo Analyzing file `basename $CFILE`
        case "$CFILE"
            in
            *.design) TYPENAME="AuraDefinitionBundle";;
            *) TYPENAME="UNKNOWN";;
        esac

        if [ "$TYPENAME" == "AuraDefinitionBundle" ]
        then
            if [ $(contains "${ARRAY[@]}" $(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")")) != "y" ]
            then
                echo baseFile from new method cFile $CFILE
                CFILENAME="$CFILE"

                replace="src/aura/"$(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")")
                echo checkChanges "${CFILENAME/$CFILENAME/"$replace"}"
                CFILE="${CFILENAME/$CFILENAME/"$replace"}"
                echo baseFile from after change method cFile $CFILE
            else
                continue
            fi
        fi
    done < final.txt
else
    echo Change file not found!
```

I can see in echo  window as :

```
 [exec] baseFile from new method cFile src/aura/camping/camping.design
 [exec] checkChanges src/aura/camping
 [exec] baseFile from after change method cFile src/aura/camping
```

but the file does not change, I even added `sed` command but the output does not change:

```
if [ $(contains "${ARRAY[@]}" $(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")")) != "y" ]
then
    CFILENAME="$CFILE"
    ARRAY+=($(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")"))
    replace="src/aura/"$(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")")
    #CFILE="${CFILENAME/$CFILENAME/"$replace"}"
    sed -i 's/$CFILENAME/$replace/' final.txt
else
    continue
fi
```

**Expected Input**

```
build/create_changes.sh
build/create_changes.sh-meta.xml
src/aura/camping/camping.design
src/aura/camping/camping.design-meta.xml
```

**Expected output**

```
build/create_changes.sh
build/create_changes.sh-meta.xml
src/aura/camping
src/aura/camping/camping.design-meta.xml
```

Comment: The `sed` command doesn't work as the single quotes prevent the variables' expansion. Did you consider doing the entire operation in an   e.g. `awk` script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can follow your logics, but this

```
awk '/\.design$/ {sub("/[^/]*$", "")} 1 ' file
build/create_changes.sh
build/create_changes.sh-meta.xml
src/aura/camping
src/aura/camping/camping.design-meta.xml
```

would yield the desired output...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete the basename of all pathnames ending in `.design`:

```
sed 's#/[^/]*\.design$##' final.txt
```

To do an in-place edit, use `sed -i` with the above expression (there are slight variations of how the `-i` flag works, but this would work with GNU `sed` for example).

The regular expression `/[^/]*\.design$` matches a `/` followed by any number of non-`/` characters and the literal string `.design` at the end of a line.